# pass url params to private route _ react Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

in router we can use {this.props.match.params.id} for matching details about some object we want to map.

```
<Route path="/userDetail/:id" exact component={UserDetail} />
```

in that component we can access :id

but in custom route how we can reach that? I found the :id in **this.props.computedMatch.params.id**

but I want to pass it to this.props.match

```
let PrivateRoute = ({ component: ChildComponent, isLogin, ...rest}) => {
      return <Route render={props => {
        if (!this.props.get.isLogin) {
            return <Redirect to="/login" />;
        } else {
          return <ChildComponent {...props} />
        }
      }} />

<Switch>
     <PrivateRoute path="/userDetail/:id"  exact component={UserDetail} />

</Switch>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also include the rest of the props you pass into the route:

```
<ChildComponent {...props} {...rest} />
```